# Как увеличивать переменную раз в секунду, не останавливая остальной код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Делаю игру на pygame, поэтому не могу останавливать весь код, так как тогда вся игра будет ставиться на паузу. Из-за этого не подходит `time.sleep()`.

Мне нужно увеличивать определённые переменные на 1 раз в секунду, я не могу просто приравнивать их к переменной времени в игре, которую реализовал вот так:

```
seconds = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000) #Секунды
```

Потому что, несколько раз за игру мне нужно будет, то прибавлять определённые значения, то обнулять эти переменные и начинать отсчёт заново.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение через второй поток:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

seconds = 0

def seconds_counter():
    global seconds

    while True:
        seconds += 1
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=seconds_counter)
thread.start()

while True:
    print('current_seconds:', seconds)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Но я бы поискал какие-нибудь варианты через сам `pygame` – думаю эта хотелка не только у вас была :)